# TableView didSelect row Issue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

So the issue is when a cell is tapped, desired data is shown and when again tapped on same cell ( again desired data is shown.)

But when one cell is selected and we again select other cell (then the data is been shown of second tapped cell but the first one is not deselected).

How can I take care of this issue?

```
var selectedIndex = -1

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) {
        self.labelViewHeightConstraint.constant = 60
        self.labelLeadingConstraint.constant = 136
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }


    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    if(selectedIndex == indexPath.row) {
        selectedIndex = -1
            print("deselect")
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {

            cell.secondView.isHidden = true
            cell.firstView.backgroundColor =  UIColor(red: 0.8588, green: 0.84705, blue: 0.8745, alpha: 1.0)
        }
    } else {
        cell.secondView.isHidden = false
    }
        self.expandTableView.beginUpdates()
        //self.expandTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic )
        self.expandTableView.endUpdates()
    }
```

Comment: It's hard to understand the question from just the constraint names that you have in the question. Can you add a small gif showing what is happening and what is expected?

Comment: Use also the `didDeselect` delegate function https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614916-tableview `optional func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
       didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`, and reverse the selection logic you did

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UPZ9cydpel_rnf-WS8PnDiakcAua8boj.    Here cell 1,2 are selected, then cell 3 is selected and selected again (so it return to its initial state) and cell i s selected which shows the content.    How should i deselect cell 1 and 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

you must disable multiple selection by,

```
self.tbl.allowsMultipleSelection = false
```

and enable single selection by,

```
self.tbl.allowsSelection = true
```

**EDIT:-**

if you want to access your old (selected cells), you should make a call like this,

```
    //first assign tag or indexPath in Cell,
    cell.tag = indexPath.row
    // or
    cell.indexPath = indexPath

    //then fetch like bellow, 
    let visibleCell = tableView.visibleCells.filter({$0.tag == self.selectedIndex})
    //or
    let visibleCell = tableView.visibleCells.filter({$0.indexPath.row == self.selectedIndex})

    //if you use ,
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    //then it will get you new cell object.
```

Comment: already done that , but getting same issue.    https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UPZ9cydpel_rnf-WS8PnDiakcAua8boj .  I want to make cell 1 and 2 back same as cell 3 when any other cell is clicked

Answer (score 0):

You can archive single selection by setting tableView property like belwo

```
tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
```

This can also be done from Attributes Inspector
[image]

Hope this helps